# My Ubuntu Server filesystem just crashed. Need some help! How to recover files or filesystem?

Tags: server, filesystem, data-recovery, boot-failure, fsck

None of my sites worked, saying that the /tmp/ folder was not writeable.

I ssh-ed into the server, and indeed, everyting was read only. I restarted with the fsck flag, and now I get a grub error.

Any tips on recovering my data? In order of importance, I need the mysql database folder(Lots of man hours went there). I can get my code back from my repository.

Its running on VMWare so before I attempt anything insane I will copy over the image and see what I can recover. It was running on ubuntu 8.10, ex3 I believe.

Do you guys have any insight to where I should navigate?

Comment: Hard to tell from what little we know. Make a working copy of the vmware disk and boot it with a desktop iso. From there you can run fsck and/or start the data recovery process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Its running on VMWare so before I attempt anything insane I will copy over the image and see what I can recover.

Yes,Make sure you have backed up existing crashed image before any attempt to recover files from there. Since you are vm image,I'm not sure about recovery procedures, may be checkout http://libguestfs.org/ It allows you to browse disk images.  (If its not a vm image,ext3grep would be really useful). You may also want to try out forensic tools sluethkit,foremost,testdisk and extcarve. HTH

Comment: Everything was in lost+found, was able to use a series of scripts and a lot of "find" to locate a backup and I went from there.. Freaking insane week, thanks for your help and insight.